# Why disabling of stage resizable dont work in javafx?

Tags: javafx, resizable, stage

When I try to `setResizable` for my scene in javaFX application it doesn't work. I still can change window size. Here's the code for my test application:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    stage.setTitle("Test window");
    stage.setWidth(300);
    stage.setHeight(200);
    stage.setResizable(false);

    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Application.launch(args);

}
```

Perhaps I missed something very simple because I am very new to JavaFX. Can anyone help me? I am using Eclipse 4.3 and JavaSDK 7u25 on Ubuntu 13.04 64bit

Comment: I have the same problem, Ian did you find the solution? I'm using windows 10

Comment: Works for me on Windows 10 and JDK 1.8.0_77

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works fine on Windows with JDK 1.7.0_25.

Maybe your problem comes from the fact that you are running your application on a Linux system (even if Ubuntu 13.04 is listed as a [supported OS](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/supportedconfigurations-1506746.html)...) The Linux support is recent and some bugs might persist.

Comment: I tested the same application on another computer with windows 7 and everything is ok. You're right, it has to be a bug in Ubuntu. Thx for help.

Answer (score 3):

```
    stage.setMaxWidth(300);        
    stage.setMaxHeight(200);
```

It prevents from picking window on bounds, but not from clicking window fullscreen button, I didn't realize howto.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug. It depends on your Operating System's system or window manager. Generally, you either need to put `stage.setResizable(false);` before or after `stage.show()`.

Although the abovementioned solution works in most cases, sometimes you have to set the maximum height and width of your stage:

```
stage.setMaxWidth(400);        
stage.setMaxHeight(400);
```