# Why javafx setResizeable(false) not work?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a javafx code like this

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/Login.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("Welcom to MSS Login");
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.show();
}
```

Here I already setResizable(false); but I still can resize the window when run app. How to set a window not resizeable?

Thanks

Comment: [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17816682/why-disabling-of-stage-resizable-dont-work-in-javafx)

Comment: Is this a bug/not support on ubuntu until now?

Comment: did you tried  using stage.setMaxWidth and stage.setMaxHeihgt

Comment: you are right: I have to use stage.setHeight(580);
        stage.setWidth(300);
        stage.setMaxWidth(580);
        stage.setMaxHeight(300);
        stage.setMinWidth(580);
        stage.setMinHeight(300);
It works now. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem today, trying to create some windows for my database management system and I clearly wanted fixed window size, non resizable, but unfortunately this is not fully supported by Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, which seems to have a different approach to how it performs with window size handlers.

However, I found the fix after none of `stageStyle("TRANSPARENT")`, `setResizable(false)` did not work.
The second one would normally work on Windows.

The fix for Ubuntu:

```
primaryStage.setMaxHeight(yourH);  
primaryStage.setMinHeight(yourH);  
primaryStage.setMaxWidth(yourW);  
primaryStage.setMinWidth(yourW);
```